# After completing my A&P are you suppose to get a temporary license? After the exam my DME just gave me a copy of my airmen certificate application

Tags: airframe-and-powerplant

I passed my exams on 17DEC2020. Currently the FAA's web site shows that I have no certificates, and shows that they are processing applicants from 25JAN2021...... what should I do?

Comment: To the close voter, what more information do you need to answer this?

Comment: I need to know where or not I should have some sort of Airmen number currently; and If I should be worried about my certs not showing up in the certificate search since they are processing airmen who graduated after me.

Comment: Have you called your FSDO?